# Print leading zeros of a floating point number

Tags: python

I am trying to print something:

```
>>> print "%02i,%02i,%02g" % (3, 4, 5.66)
03,04,5.66
```

However this is not correct. If you notice, the zeroes get correctly pre-pended 
to all the integer floating points (the first two numbers). I need it such that there will be one leading zero if the there is a single digit to the left of the decimal point.

I.e. the solution above should return:

```
03,04,05.66
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `f` as I suggested in the answer. Don't use `g`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `g`, specify and width and precision:

```
>>> print "%02i,%02i,%05.3g" % (3, 4, 5.66)
03,04,05.66
```

#### f versus g

The difference between `f` and `g` is illustrated here:

```
>>> print "%07.1f, %07.1f, %07.1f" % (1.23, 4567.8, 9012345678.2)
00001.2, 04567.8, 9012345678.2
>>> print "%07.1g, %07.1g, %07.1g" % (1.23, 4567.8, 9012345678.2)
0000001, 005e+03, 009e+09
```

When given large numbers, `g` switches to scientific notation while `f` just uses more spaces.

Similarly, `g` switches to scientific notation, when needed, for small numbers:

```
>>> print "%07.1f, %07.1f, %07.1f" % (.01, .0001, .000001)
00000.0, 00000.0, 00000.0
>>> print "%07.1g, %07.1g, %07.1g" % (.01, .0001, .000001)
0000.01, 00.0001, 001e-06
```

Comment: When to use `g` vs. `f`? Thx

Comment: @arvindpdmn See updated answer for difference between `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 4):

Use different format i.e. `f`:

```
print "%02i,%02i,%05.2f" % (3, 4, 5.66)
                 ^^^^^^
```

or with `g`:

```
    print "%02i,%02i,%05.3g" % (3, 4, 5.66)
                     ^^^^^^
```

But I would stick to `f`. I guess that's what you trying to do here (`g` can sometimes use decimal format). More info here: [formatting strings with %](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

```
'f' Floating point decimal format.
'g' Floating point format. Uses lowercase exponential format if exponent is less than -4 or not less than precision, decimal format otherwise.
```

Answer (score 4):

The format `%02g` specifies minimum width of 2. You can use `%0m.n` syntax where `m` is the minimum width and `n` is the number of decimals. What you need is this:

```
>>> print "%02i,%02i,%05.2f" % (3, 4, 5.66)
03,04,05.66
```